# localhost asking for credentials on port 8080

Tags: localhost

When I go to http://localhost:8080, it asks me for credentials but  don't know which software is running at this port. I tried with netstat but the result wasn't concluent:

```
netstat -a -b | grep 8080
```

Result:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           LAPTOP-88ASVK3T:0      LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8080              LAPTOP-88ASVK3T:0      LISTENING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "Three ways to find the process listening on a port" (https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/), add -p to your command.

Comment: I am on a windows machine. The command with -p doesn't return anything.

Comment: grep is not a Windows command, which is why I assumed *nix.  For Windows there's TCPView available in the Sysinternals package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Thank you very much, TCPView resolved my problem. PS: Sorry, I should have precised I was on Windows.